# Disable User in MultiBio 800-H Device using zk api (zkemkeeper / Interop.zkemkeeper)

Tags: c#, winforms, rfid, biometrics

I am developing an Access Control and able to disable user in other zk Devices. using below code but not only in zk 800-H device method returns true but cards is working and unlocking door.

In other device if I disable the user, swipe card device shows me user is disabled which is fine..

```
zkemkeeper.CZKEM zkApi = new zkemkeeper.CZKEM();//intialize api...
var bIsConnected = zkApi.Connect_Net("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 4370);// connecting api and tested the device is connected.

if (bIsConnected)
{
     zkApi.RegEvent(1, 65535);
     return true;
}
//in zk api for enable disable user

//in below method 1 is iMachineNumber, "1001" is UserId In machine and fasle is for enable/disable user.
var result = zkApi.SSR_EnableUser(1, "1001" , false);//no error and return true for indicate success.

if (result) 
{
     MessageBox.Show("User Disabled Successfull"); 
}
```

Comment: facing same issue, somebody pls help

Comment: @anand360 you got solution?

Comment: not yet, u have any solution for this?

Comment: @anand360 sorry for late due to lots of work and i done this by deleting and add user in to device for enable/disable card. every device work fine but MultiBio 800 create a problem. and zk says this functionality is not available in MultiBio 800. so i  just add/remove user for this kind of requirement.

Comment: @anand360 If u wish i can upload code as answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply even its too late. As the disable user didnt worked, i changed the machines, i used the normal usb fingerprint reader and stored finger template in my own created sql database and done the user enable/disable manually with sql db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue in this device as I faced the same issue and contacted the support.
team. 
Simply delete the record if you want to disable it.

Answer (score 2):

Using C#, just do this (obviously you need the employeeId)

```
    objCZKEM = new CZKEM();
    string _Name = "", _Password = "";
    int _Privilefe = 0;
    bool _Enabled = false;

    var t = objCZKEM.SSR_GetUserInfo(1, "2524", out _Name, out _Password, out _Privilefe, out _Enabled);

    t = objCZKEM.SSR_SetUserInfo(1, "2524", _Name, _Password, _Privilefe, false);
```

Comment: I just did it but the problem is not working on "zk 800-H" in other devices working fine as i say in question.